# If the interior of a non-empty closed set is empty, the complement of the closed set is dense?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Suppose $X$ is a metric space. Take $F \subset X, F \neq \emptyset$ such that $int\;F = \emptyset$. I can clearly see that $F^c$ is dense in $X$ if $X$ is a Euclidean space. But unable to see it for a general metric space. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a proof how this works in Euclidean space?

Comment: Well the boundary of F is its closure minus interior. interior is empty, so boundary =closure =F because F is closed. Suppose, BWOC, there exists an open set such that its intersection with the complement of F is empty. Which means it is a subset of F, therefore a subset of the boundary of F. But that is not possible because the boundary of F has an empty interior.

Comment: Your proof works in any space and is already better than mine. I would also add that the boundary consideration is not necessary. If there is an open set $U$ in $X\setminus F$, then $X\subseteq F$, so $F$ has nonempty interior.

Comment: Thanks so much! Of course! I see it now. If the intersection of the open set with the complement of F is empty, it must be a subset of F, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @Canine360 What theorem are you using to assert that the boundary of $F$ has empty interior? This isn't true for a general set $F$ (consider $F = \mathbb Q$ and $X = \mathbb R$). If you're asserting that it's true when $F$ is closed, isn't that essentially equivalent to what you're trying to prove? Seems your argument could be circular, but it depends on how you proved that fact you are using.

Comment: First, I considered it well known that the boundary of an open or closed set is empty, see here, e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142892/prove-that-the-interior-of-the-boundary-is-empty. It does not seem circular because the proof of emptyness of the int of the bd linked above has got nothing to do with denseness. Secondly you can forget about the boundary, see Elliot's comment above which simplifies my proof further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x\in X$ and let $r=\inf\{d(x,y):y\in X\setminus F\}$. It suffices to show $r=0$.

If $r>0$, then $\emptyset\neq B_r(x)\subseteq F$.

Edit: see OPs comment for a better answer.